# Session is not maintaining on node js

Tags: node.js, session, authentication

> I'm having one home ,login page if user get successfully login it should redirects him to dashboard . This part is working fine 
>   but if i try to open that link like http://localhost:9090/dashboard  it get opens.I Want if user is not logged in he should never be able to open dashboard page

```
module.exports = function(app, passport){
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
});


app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));
app.get('/dashboard',isLoggedIn, function (req,res) {

    res.render('dashboard.ejs');
} );
  app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
    })
 };





  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
   }

  res.redirect('/login');
  }
```

Comment: Have you used or learned about SESSION or TOKEN? This should solve your problem

Comment: Yes , i used but this  is not working in my project

Comment: But SESSION or TOKEN is the basis for judging whether the user is logged in. You need them to let your program output the corresponding data.

Comment: please provide me code sir

Comment: Share your Front end code , from where you are calling logout

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav -align-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/history">Last 15 Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>

            </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is with your route calling , check the route logout

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav -align-left"> 
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="/history">Last 15 Search</a></li>
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li> </ul>
```